# SpaCy: get token from character index

Tags: spacy

Is there an easy way to get a token from a character index? For each doc, I have a target word or phrase that is identified by character indices (start, end). The `doc.char_span()` method can return a span from those, and that works fine most of the time, but the problem arises when the indices don't map to a valid span due to mismatched tokenization (i.e. an index falls in the middle of a token).

The obvious solution is to iterate through the tokens to get a valid span as a backup, which should be fine since this is a rare occurrence, but I wonder if there's a smarter way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do something like this, but I'm not sure if that's more efficient:

```py
def get_token_for_char(doc, char_idx):
    for i, token in enumerate(doc):
        if char_idx > token.idx:
            continue
        if char_idx == token.idx:
            return token
        if char_idx < token.idx:
            return doc[i - 1]
```

Note that this is just a quick example and you'd still have to handle out-of-range errors and cases where the character index is a space that'd be folded into the `Token.whitespace` during tokenization. Currently, those cases would fall back to the token which the whitespace is attached to (which might not actually be a bad solution after all).

For ultimate efficiency, you could probably also look into implementing the above directly via [spaCy's Cython API](https://spacy.io/api/cython). If you need to make a lot of calls to this function, you could also store the character indices and their token index mapping in a dict so you only ever have to compute this once per index.